# Passing class object with List from the View to the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, html.actionlink

---

I have class which contains List:

```
public class Client
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
     }
```

How I can to pass the object of this type from View to Controller?

For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", item)
```

where item is an object of Client type.
By fact, FirstName and LastName passed successful, but Addresses passed as NULL.

Thanks any help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you new the list somewhere?

Strings are treated as value types so declaring them as a property will create the storage for them; but, the List is a reference type; so, you will need to allocate the memory for it or it will be null (as you are seeing).

Comment: I tried to create the Client copy constructor, which contains initialized data such as 
            var address = new Address {State = "NY", City = "New York"};
            this.Addresses.Add(address);
But Address List of the Client object is Empty. (I passed the Client to the Controller as @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new Client(item)))